# User Masquerading in Documentum

Tags: documentum, documentum-dfc

I am writing a document workflow application (DWA) which uses Documentum (v6.6) as its document storage mechanism.

What I'd like to do is for the application to access Documentum as a privileged user, via the Java API, and perform actions on stored documents, and have those actions appear as though the masqueraded user performed them (if they looked directly at Documentum).

How would I perform this?

For example:

User (Jane) uploads a new document via the DWA. This gets pushed into Documentum.
If Jane then accesses Documentum directly, she can see document has been uploaded and the owner is marked as Jane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by "Java API" you mean the DFC.  I think you can also do something similar in DFS (web services).

You can use `IDfSession.getLoginTicketForUser(string username)` after authenticating with an admin session.  You can use this login ticket to impersonate a user by name, and perform operations on their behalf.

http://www.nathanobert.com/dfc7/com/documentum/fc/client/IDfSession.html#getLoginTicketForUser(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Create a **Superuser** session and call `getLoginTicketForUser(String userName)` to get the Login Ticket and use this ticket as password to create the session of the user passed in the `getLoginTicketForUser(String userName)` method.